# Messed up UVs and Lightmap

Tags: three.js, blender

I want to bake my model lightmap in blender then load them all in three.js.
So in blender i set two uvs for each objects and baked ambient occlusion in second uv. finally i exported whole scene via three.js exporter into js file.
(exporter has problem that the baked texture goes for diffuse-map not light-map which is correctable by editing exported js file).
But the problem is when i load js with SceneLoader, the textures especially for my floor goes wrong, like upside down.
here is my test files: [Test Light Map](http://d-h.st/5JR)
So is there something wrong with my blender file or ...? Which loader i should use for it?
Thanks.

I just upload some images to see what i mean:
Messed up textures: [image]
After edit js file, it's get better. but still there is problem at the edges:
[image]
And specially at floor, the light-map goes wrong:
[image]

Comment: I can't debug your code, but I do see that `scene.rotation` is not zero. Something is going wrong in the coordinate change from blender to three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, <s>i don't know why, but it seems my uvs was messed up in blender.</s> i did some **recaculate normals** and **flip normals** in blender and now textures map fine on objects.
But i still need to edit exported scene to change *map:texture.png* to *lightMap:texture.png*.

[EDIT]
<s>Actually this is a bug related to three.js scene exporter</s>: [Blender Exporter - Scene Exporting](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4208)

[Final Answer]
The problem was about my model which had a negative scale in blender. i select my model, hit crtl+a then choose scale. now everything's fine.